# Change Close-Button Link when opening Link from Modal in new tab/window

Tags: 2010, modal-dialog, hyperlink

So, this is my scenario:

In SharePoint 2010, I have a custom List ("events") with multiple lookup-fields to other lists (for this example: "contact persons", "location") in it. I got two list-views, one "normal" standard-listview and a (standard) calendar-view.

Using the normal list-view, I'm able to open the information laying behind "contact persons" or "location" by clicking on the link showing in my list-field. It opens as a modal dialog. Inside *this* modal dialog, there's a "close"-Button. By clicking on this button, the modal-dialog closes. So: Everything as expected.

Now there's the possibility to view *all* details of an event by clicking on the event title in normal-listview. Not enough, it's the only way to open the details for the calendar view. These details itself are opening in a modal dialog. Now there are the lookup-links to "contact persons" and "location", too.

And here is my problem: By clicking the links ("contact persons", "location") from the modal dialog ("event details"-modal), they're opening in a new tab/window. Don't get me wrong, that's not *that* nice, but okay, and changing the response to open in the same modal doesn't change the behaviour of the close-button described hereafter. So, the *real* problem is: By using the "close"-button in this newly opened pages showing the listitems of the lookup-targetlists, the modal doesn't close (as wanted and expected), instead it redirects my end-users to the AllItems.aspx of the referring target-list.

So I want to change the behaviour of *just* these close-buttons to actually close the modal, not opening the referring lookup-lists allitems.aspx. (This is not a security issue, for they actually have read-rights to the target-lists, but in my opinion there's no need to show them every listelement if not needed)

I hope this explanation is understandable and hope you can help me out here. For more information, feel free to ask.

Best regards,
Dominik